# Asp.Net Postal MVC - The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, razorengine, postal

I'm using asp.net Postal to send emails using a background job - Hangfire to be precise.

In my template I have the following code:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Post.PostContent)
```

but i'm getting the following error:

```
 The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context
```

Below is the full template:

**Views/Emails/Example.cshtml**

```
@model ExampleEmail
To: @Model.To
From: @Model.From
Subject: @Model.Subject
Views: Text, Html
```

**Views/Emails/Example.Html.cshtml**

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<html>
 <body>
    <p>@Html.Raw(Model.Post.PostContent)</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `@Raw(Model.Post.PostContent)` seems to work